# MongoDB with Docker Authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication, docker

I have set up a docker with MongoDB Image. By default it has no password set up. I made a user and assigned it roles, which works perfectly well. But the issue is that the connection is still possible without authentication.

1. Connect with Authentication > Right Username, Right Password -> CONNECTED
2. Connect with Authentication > Right Username, Wrong Password -> CONNECTION FAILED
3. Connection without Authentication > CONNECTED

I want the 3rd point to stop working.

Answer (score 7):

***Steps:-*** 
1) Run a docker instance without authentication

```
    $ docker run --name container-name -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongodb:/data/db mongo
```

2) Create a main administrator user with admin roles

```
    $ mongo --port 27017
    $ use admin;
    $ db.createUser({user: "adminUserName",pwd: "adminPassword",roles: [{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }})
```

This will create a user in the admin database with roles "userAdminAnyDatabase". This is like a superuser.

3) Create User for a particular database

```
    $ use 
    $ db.createUser({user: "dev-read-username",pwd: "dev-read-password",roles:["read"]})  
    -- User with "read" role

    $ db.createUser({user: "dev-write-username",pwd: "dev-write-password",roles:["readWrite"]}) 
    -- User with "readWrite" role
```

For list of roles available or how to create custom roles, please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

4) Remove the docker container

```
    $ docker ps -a
    $ docker stop container_id
    $ docker rm container_id
```

5) Run the docker instance with authentication enabled

```
    $ docker run --name container-name -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongodb:/data/db mongo --auth
```

I assume you might not have started the docker container with --auth enabled. Once you start with --auth enabled, then you will not be able to connect without credentials.

Comment: I had it deployed with --auth enabled

Comment: @AqibBangash Strange it did not work with --auth enabled. I have edited my answer with detailed steps. Can you cross-verify once and see if it you missed anything just incase.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Run with auth option** to add authorizations `docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo --auth`
2. You should **create an admin user**. You can check if admin user exists using `db.getSiblingDB('admin').system.users.find()` or create one like : `db.createUser({ user: 'jsmith', pwd: 'some-initial-password', roles: [{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] });`

Source : https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mongo/

Comment: @AkshayMehta was faster than me :)

Comment: I had it deployed with --auth enabled plus i had made an admin user. Still it was accessible without auth.

Comment: Official docker container ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe i was wrong somewhere. But i got to know it the harder way. DB got compromised and hacker demanded ransom in BTCs.